# Ruby equivalent to grep -v

Tags: ruby, regex, grep

This is what I've been doing instead:

```
my_array.reject { |elem| elem =~ /regex/ }.each { ... }
```

I feel like this is a little unwieldy, but I haven't found anything built in that would let me change it to `my_array.grepv /regex/ { ... }`

Is there such a function?

Comment: I don't think so. you could create one yourself, though!

Comment: `grep_v` is a method of enumerable since Ruby 2.3

Answer (score 17):

Ruby 2.3 implements an `Enumerable#grep_v` method that is exactly what you're after.

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep_v

Comment: The obvious question is why grepv wasn't created when grep was - I find Ruby an unbelievably chaotic language.

Comment: @android.weasel I'm not "defending" its prior absence, but it took until 2012 before someone [asked for it](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6150); look up YAGNI principle. As to why it took so long to add it: when adding a new core feature to a widely-used language, caution & discussion are called for. If the API is clunky/unintuitive, it will break existing code to change it after user adoption; the alternative is to add a new API and deprecate the old one. Read: messy. Evolution often appears chaotic in hindsight.

Comment: @kelvin It took until then for someone to *request* it: people *needed* it long before. YAGNI is good for general programming, which is a mixture of design and discovery, but language developers and major library designers aren't just doing things for their own projects: to design properly they need to think about others' *needs*. Particularly given select/reject and if/unless as obvious prior art, failing to implement grepv from the start just exemplifies that sort of failure. Ruby incorporates many of the errors previous languages had already collectively 'evolved' beyond. Fool me once, eh?

Answer (score 7):

You know how `Symbol#to_proc` helps with chaining? You can do the same with regular expressions:

```
class Regexp
  def to_proc
    Proc.new {|string| string =~ self}
  end
end

["Ruby", "perl", "Perl", "PERL"].reject(&/perl/i)
=> ["Ruby"]
```

But you probably shouldn't. Grep doesn't just work with regular expressions - you can use it like the following

```
[1,2, "three", 4].grep(Fixnum)
```

and if you wanted to grep -v that, you'd have to implement `Class#to_proc`, which sounds wrong.

Comment: this answer captures the minimalist spirit of ruby -- too bad there isn't an easy way to make it work this way for all the behaviors of grep

Answer (score 6):

How about this?

```
arr = ["abc", "def", "aaa", "def"]
arr - arr.grep(/a/)  #=> ["def", "def"]
```

I deliberately included a dup to make sure all of them are returned.

Answer (score 4):

What about inverting the regex?

```
["ab", "ac", "bd"].grep(/^[^a]/) # => ["bd"]
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there's anything built-in like this, but it's simple enough to add:

```
class Array
  def grepv(regex, &block)
    self.reject { |elem| elem =~ regex }.each(&block)
  end
end
```

Note that you need to use parens around the regex when you call this function, otherwise you get a syntax error:

```
myarray.grepv(/regex/) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
my_array.reject{|e| e[/regex/]}.each { ... }
```

but really it's hard to be more concise and self-documenting. It could be written using `grep(/.../)` with some negative-lookahead pattern, but then I think it becomes harder to comprehend the overall action because the pattern itself is harder to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`Array#collect!`](http://ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/Array.html#M000721)

```
my_array.collect! do |elem|
  if elem =~ /regex/
    # do stuff
    elem
  end
end
```

**EDIT:** Sorry, then you would have to call `Array#compact` after. At least that would eliminate the second block. But it's more physical code. It depends on how much "stuff" you do.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to negate the result of the regexp match.

```
Enumerable.module_eval do
  def grepv regexp
    if block_given?
      self.each do |item|
        yield item if item !~ regexp
      end
    else
      self.find_all do |item|
        item !~ regexp
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your comments. In the end, I did it this way:

```
module Enumerable
    def grepv(condition)

        non_matches = []

        self.each do |item|
            unless condition === item or condition === item.to_s
                non_matches.push(item)
                yield item if block_given?
            end
        end

        return non_matches
    end
end
```

Not sure if that's the best way because I'm just getting started with Ruby. It's a bit longer than other people's solutions here, but I like it because it's quite analogous to Enumerable's grep option - it works with anything that can handle the ===, just like grep, and it yields the items it finds if a block was given, and either way returns an Array of those that didn't match.

I added the `or to_s` part so that any integers, for instance, interspersed in the array could be matched with the same regex, though I could imagine this might jack things sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another shot at it, with a sprinkling of [bltxd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11892)'s and [Hsiu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505904)'s answers, and hopefully retaining as much of the spirit of the original `grep` as possible (even if it's wordy):

```
module Enumerable
  def grepv(condition)
    if block_given?
      each do |item|
        yield item if not condition === item
      end
    else
      inject([]) do |memo, item|
        memo << item if not condition === item
        memo
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If you supply a block, then everything is lazy like you would expect.  If you don't supply a block, there is a little duplicate code.  I really wish that [Andrew Grimm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38765)'s answer applied in the general case.

```
>> (%w(1 2 3) + [4]).cycle(3).grepv(Fixnum)
=> ["1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3"]

>> (%w(1 2 3) + [4]).cycle(3).grepv(/[12]/)
=> ["3", 4, "3", 4, "3", 4]
```

In neither case do you pay up to `O(n^2)` for item comparison, like you would in the worst case if you do array subtraction.