# Checking each argument in a method?

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have a method that has the following...

```
def is_number?(a,b,c,d)
  # ... check if the argument is a number
end
```

Is it possible to iterate through each argument passed to `is_number?` and do what is within the method?

For example...

```
is_number?(1,3,"hello",5)
```

Would go through each argument and if the argument each argument is a number it would return true, but in this case, it would return false due to `"hello"`.

I already know how to check if an input is a number, I just want to be able to check numerous arguments all in one method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def is_number? *args; args.all?{|a| a.kind_of?(Fixnum)} end
```

Replace `Fixnum` if you want a different class to match.

Comment: I really don't understand why you insist on having an entire method definition be one line, it's horribly unreadable and there's no reason to do so.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Although I prefer it to be on one line, that is not so important. Even more important point is that there shouldn't be spaces inside parentheses, curly braces, or brackets. My understanding is that only programmers (who do not know the correct orthography) do that. Some programmers also put spaces before punctuation marks. People with correct understanding of the English puctuation will not do that. I had to revert it because I didn't want to look uneducated. Lastly, many popular Ruby source codes, for example, Ruby on Rails use a lot of one liners.

Comment: Err, where are you getting any of that from? Ruby is not the English language and is no way bound or related to its grammar rules. The Ruby documentation has spaces inside braces, so does the Pickaxe and The Ruby Programming language, so I don't know why you think that doing so would make you look "uneducated", as that would imply that some of the foremost people in the Ruby world, including Matz himself are "uneducated". I'd love to see an example of a one line method definition anywhere in the Ruby or Rails source, as I doubt that there are any, and if there are I expect they are a rarity.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I think I've seen one line methods in code written by Seattle.rb folk. Useless trivia from the talk "Ruby's past, present, and future": `rescue` used to be spelt `resque` by Matz.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm The only times I could see writing a one line method definition are in IRb and inside another method (e.g., defining a one-off singleton method on an object) given that the body is very short. That said, I don't think writing a one-line method definition is ever really more readable. Interesting, gives a whole new meaning to [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque).

Answer (score 4):

Code golfing sawa's answer: same length, but avoids `|`

```
def is_number?(*args)
  (args - args.grep(Fixnum)).empty?
end

is_number?(1,2,3) # => true
is_number?(5,2,"foo") # => false
```

It'd be nice if there was a grep -v , but currently [there isn't one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165971/ruby-equivalent-to-grep-v).

Comment: Woah, that use of `grep` with a class constant was totally unexpected, yet another crazy (awesome) use of `===`.